# Invalid conversion from char* to char?

Tags: c

I have a problem here

```
void myFunction(char string){}    

int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "HEYYY";

    myFunction(test);

}
```

Why does it give this error? `error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: If one of these answers was useful to you, please consider accepting it. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

Because `myFunction` takes in a character, not a cstring. What do you want `myFunction` to do? Did you mean `void myFunction(const char *string) { }`?

Answer (score 3):

Your function is, apparently, expecting a single character in a parameter (mis)named `string`.

You probably need to fix the prototype (definition):

```
void myFunction(char *string);
void myFunction(char string[]);
```